# Add highest and lowest values from a list into separate lists without using max and min

Tags: python

Context: I'm learning python and I'd like to save the max and min numbers from a list without using the min and max functions from python. I was trying to do something like this:

```
inp_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 5, 7, 90]

res_max = [0]
res_min = [0]

for i in range(1,len(inp_list)):
    while i <= len(inp_list):
        if inp_list[i] > inp_list[i-1]: 
            res_max[0] = inp_list[i]
        break

for i in range(1, len(inp_list)):
    while i <= len(inp_list):
        if inp_list[i] < inp_list[i-1]:
            res_min[0] = inp_list[i]
        break
```

The res_max seems to be giving the correct number, but the res_min is not the minimum number from the generated list, but simply the latest minimum number before finding a larger number.

How could I do this with "vanilla" python as much as possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `res_min = [sys.maxint]`

Comment: Why are `res_min` and `res_max` lists? You're comparing list elements to their preceding element. You should compare them to `res_min`and `res_max` respectively. Also be careful how you initialize those values. Your list could be made of negative values for example.

Comment: or `res_min = float('inf')`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thank you for your input! Is there a way to do this with loops instead?

Comment: if you don't want to use `min` and `max`, can you at least use `sorted`? that way you can just sort the list and get first and last elements, also you don't need to compare previous values in the list, just compare the current item to min and max

Comment: @Matiiss You're right, but in this situation, I'm trying to use `loops` instead

Comment: @ROO you probably also want to remove the inner while loop, and write the conditional on its own in the for loop. Your while loop is breaking after the first iteration meaning its nothing more than a wrapper around the loop body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop only once ...

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 5, 7, 90]
# set min & max to point to the first element
_min = lst[0]
_max = lst[0]
for num in lst[1:]:
  if num < _min:
    _min = num
  if num > _max:
    _max = num
print(f'min: {_min}, max: {_max}')
```

output

```
min: 1, max: 90
```

Comment: it would be better to use `for number in lst:` instead of accessing by index

Comment: The point is that I wanted to start for index 1

Comment: well, there is `itertools.islice` or just a simple slice

Comment: In general you are right - in this specific use-case OP can not any lib ..

Comment: Guys - I get your input and modified the code - thanks.

Comment: `lst_iter = iter(lst) ; _min = _max = next(lst_iter) ; for num in lst_iter:` It won't create any list copies

Comment: [Proof](https://tio.run/##xVHLasMwELzrK0ROEoSS0EsJbX8kBKHGUiKqF@t1Sb7eXSs2tZXQQy/dy0qzoxlGm694TvH5JUPfW0iBg44NNRdyAuTtubPWGzZeEfTRBO19OjLWGMs/tG8MBB2Fb1HuGKdSwUX@xgnYbw4joi9LxCbgsSObWNDt7nB7O5SzZfRahH7gmTSNa/Z7ManZxXZig8EOYtFYl1kVQSX/5eZB6KQcGiCNoZXJPOGkby4oJq58EK8M/iXfbZnKuxaH/6cmCDoZsd1QScnG/YoZUTI2W/NTixpQSFZ/0@KFWtffqLLRn@Q5lzoZVOXeqGBCgivJLq1SvoMq9198/@7IMriIYlVl2K0ex5J3/CWzcPr@Gw) that skipping first item using slices just consume memory and processing resources. It's better to initialize `_min = float("inf")` and `_max = float("-inf")` and iterate over entire list rather than slice it.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 5, 7, 90]

res_max = inp_list[0]
res_min = inp_list[0]

for i in inp_list:
    if i > res_max:
        res_max = i
    if i < res_min:
        res_min = i

print (res_max) # 90
print (res_min) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is more complicated than it needs to be. I don't see any need to use a list for the maxes. But, to solve your current problem, just set the default values to the first entry in the inp_list. So...

```
res_max = [0]
res_min = [0]
```

Could be:

```
res_max = [inp_list[0]]
res_min = [inp_list[0]]
```

Looks to me on quick glance that you were setting the "min" to a value (0) that was already less than any value in the list to be checked. So, just grab the first element of the list for the default value.

To really simplify the program, I would go with something along these lines:

```
inp_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 5, 7, 90]

res_max = inp_list[0]
res_min = inp_list[0]

for i in inp_list:
    if i > res_max: 
        res_max = i
    if i < res_min:
        res_min = i
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer offers nothing new but performance improvement of [*balderman's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69980182/10824407). For some reasons he didn't react on comments.

Use slicing to skip first element is wrong way for many reasons. Generally it just slows down code execution and increases memory consumption.

One of alternative ways to skip first element could be working with [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) rather then list itself. We can get iterator using [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and retrieve first value using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

**Code:**

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 78, 5, 7, 90]
lst_iter = iter(lst)
_min = _max = next(lst_iter)
for num in lst_iter:
    if num < _min:
        _min = num
    if num > _max:
        _max = num
print('min:', _min, 'max:', _max)
```

Using iterator significantly reduces memory usage *([proof](https://tio.run/##xVHLasMwELzrK0ROEoSS0EsJbX8kBKHGUiKqF@t1Sb7eXSs2tZXQQy/dy0qzoxlGm694TvH5JUPfW0iBg44NNRdyAuTtubPWGzZeEfTRBO19OjLWGMs/tG8MBB2Fb1HuGKdSwUX@xgnYbw4joi9LxCbgsSObWNDt7nB7O5SzZfRahH7gmTSNa/Z7ManZxXZig8EOYtFYl1kVQSX/5eZB6KQcGiCNoZXJPOGkby4oJq58EK8M/iXfbZnKuxaH/6cmCDoZsd1QScnG/YoZUTI2W/NTixpQSFZ/0@KFWtffqLLRn@Q5lzoZVOXeqGBCgivJLq1SvoMq9198/@7IMriIYlVl2K0ex5J3/CWzcPr@Gw))* and increases execution speed *([proof](https://tio.run/##xVLBasMwDL37K0wutSGMll1GWPYjo4iU2KshdoLjjPbrU0VOUjf0UNhhvsg8Pb0nye6u4dy694/Oj6P2reW@cjUGY7vWB96fB60bxVitND9VTa28rZxo@iALxvGANY6XHIHv/XFGqssjolvP3YCajtBDcYy10zGaUp8kdIcTaUxv2V9ksmWT7cL2KgzekUZOuc0I0Da/Jh0Eb2CC8qgxBcqkEy766hLEwpVPxqPEv8wXXw4a04dp/xgEQj9KHPZ4pGTzY4qEKBlDTwBXWQXAy5LvANWMA9hF//kjBGOVCYR03rggsnWVRZbP6bcYxNr4nfRgmuUro8c5ujKjr7c4L55rcc6T6qQYl3FSvpzmI0zKpw3Gt36pzflb/KXZKPF6y@N4Aw))*.